# Unable to sendkey on a password field

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im trying to press the ENTER button, the password is filling correctly so obviously the sendkeys
method is working on the password field, however ENTER is not working. No exception is raised, the
command is just not doing anything. What is the issue here ?
Note: im attempting this on a very popular email service, do some websites just block webscraping attempts ? I managed to get through 2 pages using web-scraping to reach the password field, and then it stopped working.

```
password_element = browser.find_element_by_name("passwd")
password_element.send_keys("password")
password_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
password_element.send_keys("password\n")
```

try sending the enter as \n

Comment: Thanks for thr response, tried it, didnt work

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
password_element.send_keys("password", Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thanks for thr response, tried it, didnt work.

Comment: No error,  just doesn't click or submit the form

Comment: Can I have the URL ?